# Get frequencies (absolute and relative) of levels of a categorical variable from incidence binary data by combination of columns factors

Tags: r

I would like to have the frequencies of each levels of a categorical variable (row vector) denoting ecological type (3 levels: H,F,T) of a set of 93 herbaceous plants for the observed species present (=1) conditioning by sites (3 levels: A,B,C), habitats (3 levels: 1,2,3,4) and years (3 levels: 1,2,3).

I know the procedure is passed by tapply(), but the messy thing come from the logic operator for linking levels of the categorical variable (H,F,T) for the present species (=1) accross all of the species conditioning by combination of columns factors.

This could be summarized by a 12 x 3 contingency table indicating the numbers of each ecological types (3) of species per sites (3) and habitats (4).

Ex of my data (each habitat contain 20 lines): for each species (Sp1 to Sp93) 0 for absent and 1 for present. Vector "type" contain ecological type for each species.

Site,Habitat,Year,Sp1,Sp2,Sp3,Sp4,Sp5,Sp6,...,Sp93

type= c(H,H,F,T,F,T,H,....T) # vector of length 93

Thank you in advance.

---

I hope this would help describe my data objects better.

> data = read.csv(file = "Veg_06.csv", header = TRUE)
>
> data = data[1:240, -c(1,4:7)]

Ilot #
Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... each level has 4 sublevels (from "Site") with 20 lines each, adding up to 80 lines by levels.

Site #
Factor w/ 4 levels "Am","Av","CP","CS": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

Sp #
int [1:240] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... either "0" or "1" for absence or presence of species.

veg #
Factor w/ 3 levels "H","F","T": 3 3 2 2 3 1 2 1 2 1 ... categorical factor indicating type of species.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could post a reproducible example: for example, give the results of `dput` on a subset of your data with a reduced number of species ...

Comment: PS: as usual, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I can't make a subset of my data because each level of site has 4 levels of habitats with each 20 lines representing the species for each quadrat along a transect on this habitat of a site for a given year. So for a single combination of site and habitat there is 80 lines with the columns of species. So even a subset is too big to reproduce here. I though the example of my dataset was comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would recommend http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf, Hadley Wickham's paper on Tidy Data, for some ideas on how to organize the data to be better suited to analysis.  In essence, we think of each row as a single observation.

It sounds like fundamentally, your data is a collection of `year`, `site`, `habitat`, `quadrant`(? maybe `line`, not sure from the description), `species` with the observation point being that species was observed in that site, habitat, quadrant, and year.  For simplicity, a row is present if the species is present.

In addition, there's the concept of `type`, which is associated with each species.

## Analyzing and contingency table

Putting aside the question of how to get your data into this form, let's assume that we have the data in the form described above.

```
> raw <- expand.grid(species=1:93, quadrant=1:20, habitat=1:4, site=1:3, year=1:3)
> head(raw)
  species quadrant habitat site year
1       1        1       1    1    1
2       2        1       1    1    1
3       3        1       1    1    1
4       4        1       1    1    1
5       5        1       1    1    1
6       6        1       1    1    1
```

And let's take a small sample and a large sample

```
> set.seed(100); d.small <- raw[sample(nrow(raw),20), ]
> set.seed(100); d.large <- raw[sample(nrow(raw),1000), ]
```

We can use the `ftable` function to get this into a state that we want, the 12x4 contingency table, as

```
> ftable(habitat ~ year + site, data=d.small)
          habitat 1 2 3 4
year site
1    1            0 0 1 0
     2            0 0 1 1
     3            0 1 1 1
2    1            2 1 1 0
     2            1 1 0 2
     3            0 0 1 0
3    1            2 0 0 1
     2            0 1 0 1
     3            0 0 0 0
```

This will count the same species twice if it occurs in two different quadrants of the site/habitat mixture.  We can discard the habitat and `unique`-ify to get the count across all of them

```
> ftable(habitat ~ year + site , data=unique(d.small[c('species', 'habitat','year','site')]))
```

## Transforming (tidying the source data)

To transform the data as it stands into a form like this is tricky in vanilla R.  With the `tidyr` package it gets easier (`reshape` does very similar things as well)

```
> onerow <- data.frame(year=1, site=1, habitat=2, quadrant=3, sp1=0, sp2=1,sp3=0,sp4=0,sp5=1)
> onerow
  year site habitat quadrant sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4 sp5
1    1    1       2        3   0   1   0   0   1
```

Here I'm making assumptions about what your data look like that seem reasonable

```
> subset(gather(onerow, species, present, -(year:quadrant)), present==1)
  year site habitat quadrant species present
2    1    1       2        3     sp2       1
5    1    1       2        3     sp5       1
> subset(gather(onerow, species, present, -(year:quadrant)), present==1, select=-present)
  year site habitat quadrant species
2    1    1       2        3     sp2
5    1    1       2        3     sp5
```

And now you can proceed with the analysis above.

## Merging in the species type data

Looking at your description a little closer, I think you also want to merge in a parallel vector of species type information.

```
> set.seed(100); sp.type <- data.frame(species=1:93, type=factor(sample(1:4, 93, replace=T)))
> merge(d.small, sp.type)
   species quadrant habitat site year type
1        6       16       4    2    3    2
2       27        9       2    2    2    4
3       27        8       4    2    1    4
4       32       18       1    2    2    4
5       33       18       1    1    2    2
6       45       14       4    2    2    3
7       49        6       2    3    1    1
8       54        3       3    2    1    2
9       55        2       1    1    3    3
10      56        2       4    3    1    2
11      56        1       3    1    1    2
12      57        7       2    1    2    1
13      62       18       4    2    2    3
14      70       19       1    1    2    3
15      77        2       3    3    1    4
16      80        7       3    1    2    1
17      81       17       1    1    3    2
18      82        5       2    2    3    3
19      86        9       4    1    3    3
20      87       10       3    3    2    3
```

And now you can use the `subset`, `unique`, and `ftable` approach above to get the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had a dataframe with (among other things) the columns named: "sites", "habitats", "years":

```
dfrm <- data.frame( sites = sample( LETTERS[1:3], 20, replace=TRUE),
            habitats= sample( factor(1:4), 20, replace=TRUE),
            years = sample( factor(paste("Y",1:4, sep="_")), 20, replace=TRUE) )
```

Then this will give you an additional factor-mode column that encodes the various levels of each row.

```
dfrm$three.way.inter <- with(dfrm, interaction(sites, habitats, years))
```

If you want non-populated levels then do nothing else. If you want possible levels that have no instances, then use drop=TRUE. Then you can analyze these within individual levels of the three classification variables.

Comment: So is dfrm the three classification variables ? and also what means non-populated levels ?
thank you very much.

Comment: "dfrm" is simply the name I use for the dataframe that holds the input data when no example is posted. I will post the assumed data layout that was implied by your verbal description.

Comment: In fact, sites has length 4x20 = 80 lines. 

My question was rather HOW to relate an incidence matrix with a separate vector to find frequencies of each level of that vector for each site levels. 

Can we do that using the "with" function ?

Comment: `with` is just a convenience function so you don't need to keep writing "dfrm$" in front of esach column name. It is like a localized version of `attach`. The calculation of the interaction variable will not be upset by additional lines. Please describe your data objects better. Perhaps just attaching the results of `str` on all of them